# Пишу тему на wordpress, возникли сложности с выводом статей

Tags: wordpress

Данный код почему-то НЕ выводитзаписи (post), вообще пустой контент. Думал,  что the_content  не срабатывает, но не выводится даже кнопка "читать далее". Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так

header.php:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/style/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/style/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/style.css">

    <script src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>шаблон</title>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">

<header>
    <div class="info">
        <img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/images/logo.png" alt="" />
    </div>
</header>
```

index.php:

```
  <div class="content">
    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

            <div class="post">
                <h1><a href="#"><?php the_title(); ?></a> <span><i class="icon-comment"></i><?php comments_popup_link('0', '1', '%'); ?></span></h1>
                <div class="image">
                    <img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/images/thumb.png" class="img-polaroid" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="text">
                    <?php the_content(__('подробнее...', 'punchcut')); ?>
                    <!-- <?php the_excerpt(); ?> - данная строка тоже ничего не меняет -->
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Читать полностью</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <hr />
        <?php endwhile; /* rewind or continue if all posts have been fetched */ ?>
        <div class="pagenavi"><?php if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { wp_pagenavi(); } ?></div><!--end pagination-->
        <?php else : ?>
    <?php endif; ?>    
</div>
```

footer.php:

```
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: А где цикл - основа основ WordPress. Возьмите для начала стандартную тему, посмотрите, что и как там устроено, а потом уж бросайтесь писать свою.

Comment: @KAGG Design, спасибо, что сказали, там цикл был изначально, просто не отобразилсz почему-то, но сейчас поправил, все на месте. Да, я смотрел стандартнуые темы, разбирался и вот пишу свою по документации wordpress и по видео из youtube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видимо `$post` пустой. Вызовите `the_post()` в начале шаблона

См. также:

1. [the_post()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/the_post)
2. [Цикл Wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A6%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB_WordPress)

Comment: вызвал....ничего не происходит....

Comment: @Александр В логах ошибки есть? Попробуйте для отладки вставить перед `the_content()` `var_dump(have_posts());` и `global $post; var_dump($post);`